# How to get user friend list from facebook using graph api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently I have a requirement for getting all user's friend in facebook. I am successfully able to generate auth_code (with scope: `user_friends`) , access_token.

Now When I am calling to `{user-id}/friends` [end point](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user/friends) , It is not returning users all friends, It only returns on the friends who are authenticated with that app. Is there any way in the new graph api to get all the friends of a user.

Comment: No there is no way. The question is asked roughly once a day here on Stack Overflow. Just search

Comment: facebook updated their API so it will return only those users who gave you permission , better to find it by tag friends it can give you bit similar result as you want

Answer (score -2):

A friend list - an object which refers to a grouping of friends created by someone or generated automatically for someone (such as the "Close Friends" or "Acquaintances" lists).

```
/{user-id}/friendlists
```